# CRYPTPROTECT flags for CryptProtectData function

Tags: windows, encryption, winlogon, dpapi

Stepped into DPAPI inner functionement question...

I'm (potentially) in a context pre-logon which means no user has logged on already.

Since [the CryptProtectData function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) uses current user credentials, how will it be acting ?

I was so wondering if there were any issue for this or if it was simply unusable in this context.

And... whatever can be the answer, does anyone knows what(/how to find out) the "key" used for the flag LOCAL_MACHINE. What kind of credentials/identifier is used to make the encryption specific to the machine ?

Answers/advises/redirections/suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you should use `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag for `dwFlags` parameter.

If you don't - only the `SYSTEM` user can decrypt protected data.

Comment: That's what i guessed too but i like to understand what i'm using. And it really looks like useless like... just logon to the guest session and you're free to go !
Was hoping for someone telling me "hey ! It's fine ! It's more secure than you think because..."

Comment: The internals of cryptographic key used to encrypt data is not revealed, but it is proven that this key is transferable between different computers of the same domain (roaming profiles).

Comment: if you will be using flag `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` any user on this machine (even guest) can decrypt this data.

Comment: Well, thanks for not reassuring me then ! =D (It's even worse with the roaming profiles enabled...)
Still an answer though.